# Summernote not working when using dynamic Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make multiple input forms using summernote. the problem that occurs here is that if I add the summernote box manually the code will work fine, but if I add it via jquery to dynamically get multiple tabs, the summernote input box does not appear, the results is only textarea as usual. can anyone help me?

this results from dynamic tab
[image]

i add this manualy
[image]

```js
$(".nav-tabs").on("click", "a", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(this).hasClass('add-pasal')) {
   $(this).tab('show');
  }
 })
 .on("click", "span", function () {
  var anchor = $(this).siblings('a');
  $(anchor.attr('href')).remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
  $(".nav-tabs li").children('a').first().click();
 });

 $('.add-pasal').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; 
  var tabId = 'pasal_' + id;
  $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#pasal_' + id + '">Pasal '+ id +' <span class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> </a></li>');
  $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"><div class="panel-body"><textarea name="pasal" class="summernote"><h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3></textarea></div></div>');
  $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
  console.log($('.tab-content'));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div class="tabs-container">

         <div class="tabs-left">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
           <li><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#pasal_1">Pasal 1 </a></li>
           <li><a href="#" class="add-pasal">+ Add Pasal</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="tab-content ">
           <div id="pasal_1" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="panel-body">
             <textarea name="pasal" class="summernote">
              
              <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3>
              dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <strong>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</strong> standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
              when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
              typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
              <br/>
              <br/>
              <ul>
               <li>Remaining essentially unchanged</li>
               <li>Make a type specimen book</li>
               <li>Unknown printer</li>
              </ul>
             </textarea>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where are you calling [`$('.summernote').summernote();`](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api) ??

Comment: $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"><div class="panel-body"><textarea name="pasal" class="summernote"><h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3></textarea></div></div>');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call the summernote function after you add the textarea. When running the function it only converts the objects that are available at that time, not future ones.

```
$('.add-pasal').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(".nav-tabs").children().length; 
        var tabId = 'pasal_' + id;
        $(this).closest('li').before('<li><a href="#pasal_' + id + '">Pasal '+ id +' <span class="text-danger"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> </a></li>');
        $('.tab-content').append('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + tabId + '"><div class="panel-body"><textarea name="pasal" class="summernote"><h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply</h3></textarea></div></div>');

       $("#" + tabId + " .summernote").summernote();

        $('.nav-tabs li:nth-child(' + id + ') a').click();
        console.log($('.tab-content'));
    });
```

Comment: okee a short and clear explanation, and the code goes well. Thank you very much.